# Indexing lines of text in a .txt file

Tags: python, dictionary

Say I have a .txt file. The file contains alternating lines of words and numbers:

```
Mary
156
Sue
160
Jenn
154
```

I want to put these alternating lines into a dictionary like ('Mary': 156). My first thought was to use a for-loop with the % operator but I'm still stuck on actual implementation. Is it possible to index lines in a text file? What my train of thought is so far:

```
for i in range(len(text)):
    if i%2 == 0
```

Comment: Please don't put tags in the title.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Edit2:** can do it even more simply:

```
with open("data.txt") as inf:
    data = {name.strip():int(num) for name,num in zip(inf, inf))
```

returns

```
{'Mary': 156, 'Sue': 160, 'Jenn': 154}
```

**Edit3:** (response to comment):

```
"Mary,Jade,Jenn\n".split(',', 1)
```

returns

```
["Mary", "Jade,Jenn\n"]
```

So if you only want a string up to the first comma, you can do

```
name = in_string.split(',', 1)[0]    # => "Mary"
```

Comment: I've never seen this technique. Looks very tidy. What if I have multiple names of the same length in one line and need only the first one? For example, (Mary,Jade,Jenn). Does the slice operator work [4:] for this method?

Comment: name.split(',',1)? Sorry, I've never seen this method and I'm trying to wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this

```
with open("data.txt") as data:
    for line in data:
        name = line.strip()
        number = data.readline()
        print name
        print number
```

Answer (score 0):

How about?

```
for i in range(0, len(text), 2)
```

But no need for that really as you can load it with simple:

```
s = """Mary
156
Sue
160
Jenn
154"""

lines = s.splitlines()
lines = zip(*[iter(lines)]*2)
d = dict(lines)

print d
```

Comment: You can iterate over the text directly ^^